# Python Permission Denied When Writing to file and not when read

Tags: python

Python error when opening file with:

```
f = open(file, "w")
```

but it does open with:

```
f = open(file, "r")
```

1- file is closed when running my app

2- app is running as administrator

3- file is not set as read only and should have the write permission (using windows)

and still I am getting this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.txt'
```

I couldn't fix the problem if anyone have any idea please let me know.

Comment: Check the processes to understand if Python (or another process) is still hanging onto an old file handle. [Process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is a very useful tool to have lying around - especially the portable version.

Comment: What about `f = open(file, "a")`? Does that also give you the same error?

Comment: Are you running on linux? Make sure the file/folder you're writing to has write permissions: Run `ls -la /path/to/file` to see if you have write permissions. If not, you can `chmod +w /path/to/file` to apply write permissions to your user.

Comment: @sleepystar96 - Step 3 states the user is (unfortunate enough) to be using Win.

Comment: ah thanks missed that @S3DEV

Comment: @sleepystar96: Folder permissions on Linux don't pay any role in this case.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Answer (score 0):

`PermissionError: [errno 13]` permission deniederror occurs when you try to access a file from Python without having the necessary permissions.

**SOLUTIONS N.1**

Try specifying the full path to the file. The error could be that when not using a full path, Python uses the current directory and that is different from the default.

```
f = open('C:\my folder\myOutput.txt', 'w')
```

**SOLUTION N.2**

```
path = Path("path/to/my/file.txt")
path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with open(path, "w") as file:
    ...
```

**SOLUTION N.3**

```
import os

path = r"my/path/to/file.txt"
assert os.path.isfile(path)
with open(path, "r") as f:
    pass
```

**SOLUTION N. 4**

```
from os import path

file_path = path.relpath("xxx/file.txt")
with open(file_path) as f:
    <do stuff>
```

Comment: As previously stated, user is on Win; on which *nix file permissions are irrelevant.  This is also clearly shown in your No. 1 answer, by using `C:`.

Comment: @S3DEV Okay, I'm sorry. I just wanted to try to help. I have entered other solutions. I hope they work.

Comment: @Elia Khazzaka I have updated my answer and entered other solutions